# How to fit multiple background images to any screen

Tags: html, css

i´m building a website that has different background images as you scroll down.
The problem I am facing is that each background image is not fitting the screen (in terms of the height). My images won't fit the whole screen unless I set them to have 1100px and therefore will not be fitting the 100% of my height, but let's say they will be going down, on those 20% who are going to come as I scroll down.
I would like to have my images fit 100% of the screens height, without being cut
and going bellow the page.

```
.container {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 1vh;

}

.parallax {
  background: url("quem-somos.png") ;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parallax2{
  background: url("servicos.png") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}

.parallax3{
  background: url("depoimentos.png") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}

.parallax4{
  background: url("comecando.png") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}

.parallax5{
  background: url("sac.png") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 1000px;
  background-attachment: scroll;;
  width: 100%;
}

.parallax6{
  background: url("onde-atuamos.png") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I have put all of the images inside the container

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="parallax" id="about">

            </div>
            <div class="parallax6" id="operations">
            </div>

          <div class="parallax2" id="servicos">
          </div>

          <div class="parallax3" id="Depoimentos">
          </div>

          <div class="parallax4" id="Comecando">
          </div>

          <div class="parallax5" id="sac">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: well it a logically impossible. Aslong as the Image ha not the exact same ration as the screen (which in most cases do not apply) then the image either needs to be cut or streched out proportion to fit. So what you ask is not possible. Either have it streched, cropped or not fill the whole space. A reason why I personally disliek using images as background and going for repeatable vector graphics.

Comment: @tacoshy Hey thanks for you answer, how can i strech each image to the screen so it fits the height at 100%?

Comment: use `background-size: cover;` to make sure that the image doesnt strech to the very bottom of the content but only to the screen size use: `background-attachment: fixed;`with `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: @tacoshy I want my background images like the ones on the link(https://atom.io/), but the background images fit the screens height

Comment: @tacoshy do i put that on the container or in the parallax???

Comment: `html,body,.container,.container>div{ width:100vw; height:100vh; }`

Comment: those are CSS definitions for the bacgroudn image. Also your link, does not fill out the entire screen. It is cropped with other screen rations and is not an image to completly fill the entire screen. Its a picture isnide a container which is centered and does not extend to the sides. @StackSlave this wont help at all. 100vh will definetly stretch the image outside the screen as 100vh is 100% of the screen hight not the bowser height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to set the div height to the screen height, you have to make sure html and body have a min height of the screen and also set the background-size: cover
Also .image1 .image2 in my case are direct children of the body element in my example

```
html, body {
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .image1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .image2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

Comment: That works to a certain point, but the bottom of the images gets cut out.
 I would like to have the images fit the screen. 

Lets say, image 1 fits 100% of the screen, as I am scrolling down I keep on seeing image 1 until I can see 100% of the image 2. That second image must be fitting 100% of the screen too, without being cut out.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the child divs do the heavy lifting by setting heights to 100vh - the margin on top of the container.

https://jsfiddle.net/x2h0mat7/

Here's a working example with the original html:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="parallax" id="about">

    </div>
    <div class="parallax6" id="operations">
    </div>

    <div class="parallax2" id="servicos">
    </div>

    <div class="parallax3" id="Depoimentos">
    </div>

    <div class="parallax4" id="Comecando">
    </div>

    <div class="parallax5" id="sac">
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the css:

```
.container {

  margin-top: 1vh;
}

.container>div {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 1vh);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}

.parallax {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1600x1200/0000FF/");
}

.parallax2 {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1600x1200/990000/") no-repeat center;
}

.parallax3 {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1600x1200/ffee66/") no-repeat center;
}

.parallax4 {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1600x1200/66eeff/") no-repeat center;

}

.parallax5 {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1600x1200/ee66ff/") no-repeat center;
}

.parallax6 {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1600x1200/ffee66/");

}
```

Comment: I have tried doing that and that divs image disappears... Any thoughts?

Comment: I've updated my example to show what I was thinking.